# Why does Rails take 20+ seconds to load 5kb of html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am using ruby 2.0.0, and Rails 4.1.1,  sprockets-rails (~> 2.0), sprockets (2.11.0).

My suspicions are it may have to do with fiepicker, carrierwave (which i commented out everything relating to it), or asset pipeline.

I am not sure how to diagnose the problem or what config settings to adjust.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/gmLhyRh.png]

Comment: Your starting point would be the Rails logs. Request the page, then check your logs for a line like `Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 2.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)`.

Comment: It says what you wrote. My numbers are 22000ms for views and 1 ms for active record. How would I diagnose deeper in my views? Does this count for assets and image hosting api?

Comment: The lines afterwards sees a /convert path that is for filepicker, but raises an active controller routing error saying no matches for /get.  The page in the browser loads fine. This is just the server logs

Comment: I would suggest the [Rack Mini Profiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler), which gives you more insights into the time spent rendering views.